# required input in activeadmin form not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, formtastic

I am using active_admin.  I am trying to make a form field required in activeadmin:

```
  input :team, as: :select, required: true, collection: Team.all.pluck(:name, :id), include_blank: "Please enter a team", allow_blank: false
```

It is only on this specific activeadmin page that i want this validation.  It should not exist anywhere else in the site, so I don't want to do it in the model.

For some reason, the code above is not working.  While the form field does show a `*`, it still submits.  How can I make this input required only on this page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is `input_html: {required: true}`

```
# adds .required class to the input's enclosing <li> element - form can still be submitted
input :team, required: true   

# adds required attribute to the <input> element - form cannot be submitted
input :team, input_html: {required: true}
```

Comment: Works, verified. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is really a Formtastic issue, not Active Admin. I don't think you can combine `allow_blank: false`, `include_blank: 'text'` and `required: true`. Try `include_blank: false` and `hint: 'Please enter a team'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Model, as: "Model" do
    Formtastic::FormBuilder.perform_browser_validations = true
    # all code
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Add this line to your related active_admin file

Formtastic::FormBuilder.perform_browser_validations = true

ActiveAdmin.register Model, as: "Model" do   
  Formtastic::FormBuilder.perform_browser_validations = true  
    # all code  
end

Add input_html: {required: true}  to field which you want to make it required
input :first_name, input_html: {required: true}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).